# Simplistic C program to encrypt and decrypt a string

Tags: c, cryptography

I wanted to improve a crypter from internet. I found it poor and modified it.

Do you like it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

//Simple C program to encrypt and decrypt a string

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int scnt;
  int scnt2;
   int i, x;
   char str[512];
   printf("\nCrypter ver0.1\n");
   printf("\nYou need enter or create two keys for security\nWrite they in safe place\nTHIS PROGRAM CONTAINS BUGS");
   printf("\nPlease enter a string:\t");
   gets(str);

   printf("\nPlease choose following options:\n");
   printf("1 = Encrypt the string.\n");
   printf("2 = Decrypt the string.\n");
   scanf("%d", &x);
   printf("Create or Provide Exist Key:\n");
   scanf("%d", &scnt);
   printf("Create or Provide Exist Second Key:\n");
   scanf("%d", &scnt2);



   //using switch case statements
   switch(x)
   {
   case 1:
      for(i = 0; (i < 512 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
        str[i] = str[i] + scnt - scnt2; //the key for encryption is 3 that is added to ASCII value
        printf("\nYou Encrypted String! You now in safe");
      printf("\nEncrypted string: %s\n", str);
      break;

   case 2:
      for(i = 0; (i < 512 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
        str[i] = str[i] - scnt + scnt2; //the key for encryption is 3 that is subtracted to ASCII value
        printf("\nYou Decrypted String!\n");
      printf("\nDecrypted string: %s\n", str);
      break;

   default:
      printf("\nYou entered wrong number Select from 1 to 2\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

yes I know it contains so many bugs but I tested it on a long string and it worked (bugs are: 1. spaces don't work 2. in some keys it halts 3. unstable) but it decrypts fully without mistakes (tested around 50+ keys).
I made it so hard to hack even if you have source of program because my crypter uses 2 keys what makes it more hard to hack!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: First rule about software security mechanisms: Don't invent your own while you haven't invested thousands of hours in the field.

Comment: Increasing the first key by one and decreasing the second key by one yields the same encryption. Your actual key is `scnt - scnt2`, a single number. You have the user remember two numbers, but provide no better encryption than with a single number. This is typically called the ["Cesar cipher"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_Cipher), the simplest and oldest cipher in the books. Decoding the text with all possible keys and seeing which of the results makes sense is trivial. Do not rely on this cipher for anything.

Answer (score 3):

**Use modern C**

`gets()` has been dropped from the C standard library since C11 (12 years) and was even then considered poor practice.

Consider alternatives like using `fgets()` for all user input.

**Test not needed**

`i < 512` is useless.  For that to be false, prior `gets()` would have overrun `str[]` and that is *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
// for(i = 0; (i < 512 && str[i] != '\0'); i++)
for(i = 0; str[i]; i++)
```

**Simplify**

Code does either `+ scnt - scnt2` or `- scnt + scnt2`.  Consider forming the difference once.

```
int diff = scnt - scnt2;
...
str[i] += diff;
...
str[i] -= diff;
```

**Use auto-formatting**

**Early *null character***

`str[i] + scnt - scnt2` may result in 0 and then the later `printf("\nEncrypted string: %s\n", str);` will not print the entire *string*.

**Overflow**

As `str[i] + scnt - scnt2` may overflow or easily result in a value outside the `char` range.  Re-code to prevent overflow and nicely handle out-of-range results.  Perhaps a limit on `scnt, scnt2` like code did with `x`?

Comment: thank you for your answer i will use your tips to improve my crypter!